# How to change some words of a string to BOLD?

Tags: android, regex, string

This is the string which i am getting from web using json api in my code:

```
String content = "<strong><em>India is the world’s hub for child sex trafficking</em>
</strong></p>\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong><em>Nearly 40,000 children are
abducted every year… </em></strong></p>\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong<em>
Every8 minutes a girl child goes missing in India!</em></strong></p>\n<p><strong>Priti
Pathak</strong></p>\n<p>MEET Shivani Shivaji Roy, Senior Inspector, Crime Branch, Mumbai
Police, as she sets out to confront the mastermind behind the child trafficking mafia,"
```

In this string whatever the text is in

```
"<strong><em> TEXT </em></strong>"
```

I want to display it BOLD. So for the above string

```
<strong><em>India is the world’s hub for child sex trafficking</em></strong>
```

will be displayed as 
***India is the world’s hub for child sex trafficking***
      .  This should happen for entire string. This is the code which i am using:

```
 int startIndex = content.indexOf("<strong><em>")+13;  // 13 because <strong><em> has 13 characters

        String substring = content.substring(startIndex, startIndex+200);
         int subendIndex = substring.indexOf("</em></strong>");
         int endIndex = startIndex + subendIndex;

SpannableString s = new SpannableString(content);
s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startIndex, endIndex, 0);
textview.setText(s, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
```

This code is working but it is setting bold text only to the text whichever is first within strong tag and not to the rest. Because I am setting bold text only to the first tag.

How should i get the startIndex, endIndex of all the "strong tags" and so i can set

```
s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), startIndex, endIndex, 0);
```

to all the texts and also the number of times i would have to set the span.

I though of using regex also but i dont know how to get indexes using it. Any help would be nice. Thankyou !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier way is to use the `Html` class:

```
s = Html.fromHtml(content);
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) for the details.

Answer (score 3):

**This is the simple  way**

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Tv);
            String  Title="I N <big>D</big> I A";
            TV.setText(Html.fromHtml(Title));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only bold some strings then I recommend Html.fromHtml. A short sample:

```
String str = "<b> bold text</b> unbold one";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Here's a [list](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) of html tags supported by textview.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular HTML tags in Strings, This text uses **bold** and *italics* by using inline tags such as  within the string file.. Refer this link [Hope this Link would be helpful for you!](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html)